# Macro asm inline error

Tags: gcc, assembly

I am trying to use following macro:

```
#define M_MA(out, L_v, var1, var2)({ \
    asm volatile(  \
    "movswl %2, %%edi\n\t" \
    "movswl %3, %%ebx\n\t" \
    "imull %%edi, %%ebx\n\t" \
    "sall $1,%%ebx\n\t" \
    "cmpl %4,%%ebx\n\t" \
    "cmove %5,%%ebx\n\t" \
    "addl %1, %%ebx\n\t" \
    "jno out%=\n\t" \
    "cmovg %5, %%ebx\n\t" \
    "cmovl %4, %%ebx\n\t" \
    "out%=: nop\n\t" \
    "movl %%ebx, %0\n\t" : "=r"(out) : "r"(L_v), "m"(var1), "m"(var2), "r"(-2147483648), "r"(+2147483647) : "%ebx","%edi");  })
```

When it is used inside a file compiled using optimizations I get:

```
error: ‘asm’ operand has impossible constraints
```

**var1** and **var2** are 16 bits words. **out** and **L_v** are 32 bits words.

After some reading I think the problem is that the compiler need more registers than available but I am not sure about it. If that is the problem I have no idea how to use less registers than now or how to mend the mistake.

I am using gcc over Linux in a 32 bits platform.

Anyone could clarify something about that?

Regards

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to load `%ebx` and `%edi` with `var1` and `var2` manually? Wouldn't removing the `movswl` instructions+clobber list and changing the constraints of to `[...] "D"((int32_t)var1), "b"((int32_t)var2)` work?

Comment: Why do `out` and `L_v` need to be in registers, and `var1` and `var2` in memory? If it doesn't matter, you could use the constraints of `"r,m"` to allow either memory or register. (Even better, use `"g"` for `L_v`, since it can be an immediate value too.)

Answer (score 4):

"I have no idea how to use less registers than now" -- how about using immediates instead of registers for the two maxint/minint constants? (Ah, `cmov` does not take immediates. But you can store the constants in `%edi` for yourself instead of requiring the compiler to set it up in a different register in advance).

Also, why do you want to construct everything in `%ebx` and then copy it to a different register at the very end? None of the operations are ones for which `%ebx` has a special meaning, so simply replacing `%%ebx` with `%0` throughout and declaring it `"&=r"` instead of `"=r"` will be either a win or at least not a loss.

Comment: +1 If the OP wants to keep them as parameters they are great candidates for the `"m"` constraint (though *they* of course need to be loaded manually to a free register).

Comment: An early-clobber output register, i.e. one that is guaranteed to be different from any input register. See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Modifiers.html).

Comment: Applying some of your tips (using %i instead %ebx, using casting instead doing it inside macro) I solved the problem but when I apply -O3 flag to gcc I get bad results sometimes. Do you know why? Current code seems as [Code](http://pastebin.com/XYYdr4jF) Macro is defined as volatile so I don't know why I get differents results depending on apllying optimization flags.

Comment: If you can reproduce the wrong behavior, an obvious avenue would be to inspect the generated code with `gcc -S`. Another possibility is that somewhere _outside_ the inline macro you're doing something dodgy that confuses the optimizer (signed integer overflow and variable aliasing through wild pointer casts are classics).

Comment: I found sometimes gcc generates "imull %eax,%eax" which is not correct as both imull operands must be different. Any way mend it?